# Trigger Jenkins job on code commit to Azure repository

Tags: jenkins, azure-devops, jenkins-pipeline, azure-repos

I have a Jenkins job running on my localhost:8080. I want to trigger this job automatically whenever there is a commit on Azure repos (Azure DevOps).

Any advise on how I can achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: What research have you done? What have you tried?

Comment: @DanielMann I came across the service hooks on Azure DevOps. When I proceed with it, I'm required to enter my jenkins base url. However, I can't use localhost in there. So I was wondering if there's an alternative to this method or if there's a workaround regarding the base url.

Comment: 'localhost' means 'yourself' - 127.0.0.1;   An ADO build agent will view 'localhost' as itself, ie.  the agent that ADO is running on;   You need to find the actual name or IP address of the machine where the jenkins job is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Jenkins job running on your localhost:8080. You need to create your [self-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) on the local machine which your jenkin server can communicate to. Then you need to create a azure pipeline to be triggered on Azure repos commit and run this azure pipeline on your self-hosted agent. You can check out below workarounds:

- Enable `Trigger builds remotely` on Jenkins

  Go the the Build Triggers Tab of your jenkins pipeline configure page--> Then check Trigger builds remotely--> Specify a Token (will be used in the URL)
- Define a secret variable to host your jenkins password(eg. password) in azure devops pipeline:
- Add a bash task in your azure devops pipeline to run the below curl command

  ```
  #token must be the same with the token you entered in above step
    curl -u $(username):$(password) http://localhost:8080/job/myproject/build?token=anytoken
  ```
- Targeting your self-hosted agent pool to run your azure devops pipeline on self-hosted agent.

There is another workaround using [Jenkins queue job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/jenkins-queue-job?view=azure-devops) task.

- Create a API Token in your Jenkin server.

  Go your jenkin account configure page. To create a API token.
- Add Jenkins queue job task in azure devops pipeline
- Click the `Manage link` to create a `jenkins service connection`--> In the newly opened page-->Create Service connection-->Select Jenkins--> Next

  Enter the required information. Note: url is your local jenkin server. username is your user account for jenkin server, the Password is the API Token You generated in above step.

Another workaround is to configure the `Poll SCM` build triggers on your jenkins job. So that the jenkin server will periodically poll the source code and queue the job if there is new commit.

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63278454/integrating-local-jenkins-setup-with-azure-dev-ops) for more information.