# login to Azure Container App with Jenkins Pipeline Failes: "Access is Denied" Error

Tags: azure, jenkins-pipeline, azure-cli, azure-service-principal, azure-container-apps

I'm encountering an issue where my Jenkins pipeline fails to log in to Azure, resulting in an "Access is denied" error.

I'm working on automating a process where every push to GitHub triggers a new Docker image build, which is then uploaded to an Azure Container App.

Currently, my setup includes:

- An Azure Container App hosting my server image (analytics-log-server).
- A Jenkins pipeline configured to:
- - Trigger a build on a GitHub push. [ Pass ]
- - Build a Docker image from the repository. [ Pass ]
- - Push the image to Docker Hub. [ Pass ]
- - Attempt to connect to Azure. [ Fail ]

some more detailes:

- I've installed Jenkins locally and it's accessible via localhost:8080
- I'm using Ngrok to expose a public address for the GitHub webhook.
- The connection to Azure, as specified in the Jenkinsfile, is established using an Azure Service Principal.
- I've configured the relevant credentials in Jenkins as a Service Principal type.
- When trying to connect using the same command with the same values in the terminal, it connects successfully.

The output in Jenkins:

````
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Deploy to Azure Container App)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withCredentials
Masking supported pattern matches of %AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID% or %AZURE_TENANT_ID% or %AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET% or %AZURE_CLIENT_ID%
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ az login --service-principal -u **** -p **** -t ****
Access is denied.```


the Jenkins File:
````

pipeline {
agent any

```
environment {
    // Define environment variables
    DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME = // my Docker Hub username
    DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME = // my Docker image name
    IMAGE_TAG = "${DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME}/${DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME}:${BUILD_NUMBER}"
    RESOURCE_GROUP = 'AI-Dev'
    CONTAINER_APP =  // name of my container app on Azure
    // Credentials IDs
    DOCKER_HUB_CREDENTIALS_ID =  // The ID of Docker Hub credentials in Jenkins
    AZURE_CREDENTIALS_ID =  // The ID of Azure service principal credentials in Jenkins
    
}

stages {
    stage('Checkout') {
        steps {
            // Checks out the GitHub repository
            checkout scm
        }
    }

    stage('Build and Push Docker Image') {
        steps {
            script {
                // Login to Docker Hub
                
                withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: DOCKER_HUB_CREDENTIALS_ID, usernameVariable: 'DOCKER_USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'DOCKER_PASSWORD')]) {
                    
                    sh "docker login -u $DOCKER_USERNAME -p $DOCKER_PASSWORD"
                }
                // Build the Docker image
                sh "docker build -t $IMAGE_TAG ."
                // Push the Docker image to Docker Hub
                sh "docker push $IMAGE_TAG"
            }
        }
    }

    stage('Deploy to Azure Container App') {
        steps {
            script {
                // Login to Azure using the Azure CLI
                
                withCredentials([azureServicePrincipal('008ad470-0ab1-4486-a07c-e5b17cc18ace')]) {
                    sh 'az login --service-principal -u $AZURE_CLIENT_ID -p $AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET -t $AZURE_TENANT_ID'
                }
                // Set the Azure subscription
                sh "az account set --subscription \${AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID}"

                // Deploy the image from Docker Hub to the Azure Container App
                sh """
                az containerapp update \\
                    --name $CONTAINER_APP \\
                    --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP \\
                    --image $IMAGE_TAG \\
                    --registry-login-server index.docker.io \\
                    --registry-username $DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME \\
                    --registry-password $DOCKER_PASSWORD
                """
            }
        }
    }
}

post {
    always {
        // Echo for debugging purposes
        echo "Build, push, and deployment process completed."
        echo "Docker Image: $IMAGE_TAG"
        echo "Deployed to Azure Container App: $CONTAINER_APP in Resource Group: $RESOURCE_GROUP"
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Double-check that the credentials have the correct values for the AZURE_CLIENT_ID, AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET, AZURE_TENANT_ID, and AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID environment variables. If the credentials are correctly configured, then you may need to check the permissions of the Service Principal in Azure.

Comment: References:
-   [Tutorial: Deploy to Azure App Service with Jenkins and the Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/jenkins/deploy-to-azure-app-service-using-azure-cli#troubleshoot-the-azure-cli)
-   [Create an Azure service principal with Azure CLI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest)
-   [Tutorial: Deploy from GitHub to Azure Kubernetes Service using Jenkins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/jenkins/deploy-from-github-to-aks#create-a-jenkins-project)

Comment: Kindly refer to these documents and verify if these steps are completed-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/jenkins/configure-on-linux-vm
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/jenkins/deploy-to-azure-app-service-using-azure-cli

Especially Add Azure service principal to a Jenkins credential section in the second link because inorder to connect Jenkins with Azure, you need to use an Azure Service Principal to authenticate and access Azure resources.  Also verify the azure plugins under manage plugins- Azure Credentials, Azure App Service and Azure VM Agents

Comment: Still the same issue. The thing is that when using the same command with the same values in the terminal, it works. So i guess its something to do with permissions specificly on jenkins but i cant figure it out

Comment: Omer, it would be great if you can share screenshots of your jenkins configuration, specifically the permission section for me to troubleshoot it further.

Comment: Also I would request you to-
Make sure the Azure Service Principal credentials you configured in Jenkins are correct and have the necessary permissions to access the Azure resources you're trying to deploy to.
Check that the Azure subscription ID, tenant ID, client ID, and client secret are all correct in your Jenkinsfile.
Verify that the Azure CLI is installed and up to date on the machine running Jenkins.
Check that the Jenkins user has the necessary permissions to run the az login command and access the Azure resources you're trying to deploy to.

Comment: i checked again the credentials and it well configured. 
I'm new on jenkins so i dont know exectly all the features but i found a section (Dashboard->Manage Jenkins->Clouds) and there i set up an instance that using the same credentials for Azure Service Principal and it did seem to connect to my Azure reasource (it suggested my Resource group name in the dropdown and output "Successfully verified Azure configuration").
can you please guide me to the sections on Jenkins, Azure or Entra that have the relevant configurations?

Answer (score 1):

The "Access is denied" error when trying to connect to Azure from Jenkins pipeline could be caused by incorrect credentials or insufficient permissions. In addition to the points I have mentioned in comment section. Would request you to kindly check below things once.

1. Double-check that the Azure Service Principal credentials are correct and have the necessary permissions to access the Azure Container App
2. Make sure that the Azure Service Principal credentials are correctly configured in Jenkins i.e _**Username with password**

   - **Username**: Service principal  `appId`
   - **Password**: Service principal  `password`
   - **ID**: Credential identifier (such as  `AzureServicePrincipal`)
     [image: Jenkins-creds here]
3. Check under Subscription-> IAM-> Role Assignment->
   your jenkins have `contributor` access or not
   [image: Jenkins-role]
4. Make sure you have below two plugins enabled.
   [image]
   [image]

If all these are correctly updated, then you should be able to connect your Jenkins to azure. For additional details kindly refer to below shared documents.

References:

- [Tutorial: Create a Jenkins pipeline using GitHub and Docker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/jenkins/pipeline-with-github-and-docker#tutorial-create-a-jenkins-pipeline-using-github-and-docker)
- [Deploy to Azure Container Apps from Azure Pipelines - Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/azure-pipelines#configuration)
- [Deploy to Azure App Service with Jenkins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/jenkins/deploy-to-azure-app-service-using-azure-cli)
- [Similar Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63278454/integrating-local-jenkins-setup-with-azure-dev-ops)